# file_field_widget_form error when programatically creating nodes

Tags: 7, forms

I have a simple routine which I use to create nodes. The logic is something like this:

```
function make_node($node_type, $field_data) {
    foreach ($field_data as $k => $detail) {
        $field_key = _get_field_keys('field_' . $k);
        $field_key = $field_key[0];

        $node -> {'field_' . $k}[$node -> language][0][$field_key] = $detail;
        $form_state['values']['field_' . $k] = $detail;   
    }
}
```

Then I run drupal_form_submit and it returns any errors from that and everything is great.

I'm having an issue with creating nodes which have a file upload field which uses the file u widget. I get the error:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in file_field_widget_form()
```

I had a look at the offending line (line 511 of modules/file/file.field.inc) and I can see why it occurs, the function file_field_widget_form has an argument called $element, which is supposed to have an index 0, but when I set up the form programatically, that index is not set up.

When I make a node of the same type using the web interface, I can see that the $elements array is set up with the 0 index before even submitting the form.

How do I rectify this issue, do I need to call something else *before* making my form programatically? I'm using Drupal 7 if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is actually a problem in Drupal itself. In modules/file/file.field.inc the function field_form_get_state has a line like this near the bottom (just before the return statement):

```
$elements['#file_upload_description'] = theme('file_upload_help', array('description' => '', 'upload_validators' => $elements[0]['#upload_validators']));
```

The issue is a small if condition a few lines back which looks like this:

```
if (($field['cardinality'] == FIELD_CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED || $delta < $field['cardinality']) && empty($form_state['programmed'])) {
    $elements[$delta] = $element;
    ...
    some more stuff
}
```

Since I am submitting the form programmatically with `drupal_form_submit()`, it adds in `$form_state['programmed']`; thus, the control statement's condition fails, and `$elements[0]` does not exist.